# using java - How to read code signing/cert information from jar

Tags: java, jar, code-signing, jarsigner, jar-signing

I'm looking for a way to read the code signing/certificate information form JAR files.

Actually, I do want to know about the jar:

- Is it signed?
- Is the signature valid (changed after signing)?
- Was the TSA provided during signing?
- What certificate was used for signing (CN, O, ...)?
- When will the signature/certificate expire?

I'm thinking of calling the `jarsigner` as exec via Java and parse its command line output to retrieve this information, but that looks awful after starting right now.

Is there any other way to get this information?

I know validation could be done by some approaches I've seen here, but what about the information I do want to get?

Comment: It doesn't matter when the certificate expires. It was valid when it signed the JAR file. It isn't the same as an SSL certificate in this respect,

Comment: @EJP : It does matter. Not only, but specially if there was no TSA provided on signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use Jar package to read manifest file.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html

There are information in Oracle docs how to validate if files were tempered with
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_Validation

I'm not sure how to check certificate tho.

**Update**

According to documentation you can get certificate and timestamp information jusing Jar utils package https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/time-of-signing.html#APIENHANCE.

Check https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.util.jar.JarEntry *SecNav.java* example (getting certificate and codesigner for Jar entries).